# Eliminating double, triple, quadruple, etc. spaces in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

I receive a lot of text files like this

```
   120
    1
   230
   1.3
    3
  13240
    7
```

In addition, there is some regular text there too (single space between the words). So I would like to come up with a way to automatically "search and replace" two, three, four, five, etc. spaces (all but single spaces) so that the above numbers no longer have any spaces in front of them. Any thoughts? Maybe a macro would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a macro, actually, this can be done simply with the Find and Replace tool.

1. Open the Find and Replace dialog box (control+H by default).
2. If the Search Options section is not currently displayed, press the "More > >" button to display it.
3. In the Search Options section, check the "Use wildcards" checkbox.
4. In the "Find what:" field, enter a single space followed by `{2,}` .
5. In the "Replace with:" field, either leave it blank to remove the leading spaces entirely or put a single space to replace all repeated spaces with a single one.
6. Press the Replace All button.

Note that if you choose to remove leading spaces entirely, this may backfire if you have any lines beginning with just a single space; these will still have the space there, while the ones that used to have multiple spaces at the beginning will have them all removed.

Comment: thanks, it works but it only removes empty spaces before the numbers. How can I remove the empty spaces after the numbers? (to the right from them)